# Is there currently a problem with inserting images?

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, image-upload

I'm seeing some *really* strange things when I'm trying to embed images using the `Image` button now.
When I'm inserting *my* image, something entirely different turns up. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

What I tried to include below is an image of the `Ask a public question` text on this very page. But I'm getting the following image that I have ***no*** affiliation with. If the image changes somehow, what is (or *was*) below is a table with some regression results...

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359772/i-am-getting-the-wrong-image-when-uploading-a-picture

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ same image in an answer

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  It sure is! Didn't catch that...

Comment: @Yatin Are you saying that one of the images in the linked post above turned up in another answer? Sounds reasonable. Which post by the way?

Comment: @vestland I've just seen the title. Shot in the dark. np